# Group area in asp .net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, routes

What's the best way to split ASP .NET MVC Application into 2 parts? Is now has 8 areas + one common area (Login, some base methods etc). 8 areas are logically separated into 2 blocks so it even can be located on different applications, but have to exist on the same domain.

So the routes I have: 
domain/area{1-8}/controller/view

routes I want:
domain/logicalblock/area{1-4}/controller/view

Can I get 2 applications for it?

Comment: Can't you just create a separate MVC Application project under the same solution and separate your solution there?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could define the route like this in Area1AreaRegistration.cs

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Area1",
            "Logicalblock/Area1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Area1.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

and so on for all areas.

Comment: Is works, thanks. But I want to get this result automatically. With custom razor engine maybe.. don't know. Any ideas?